# Get all dynamic fields of a groovy class

Tags: mongodb, grails, dynamic, groovy, field

In my application I need to use dynamic fields of a class.
The object is persisted into MongoDB (also dynamically) from json request:

```
Object obj = new Object()
def objectData = request.JSON.object
for(item in objectData) {
    obj[item.key] = item.value
}
obj.save(flush: true)
```

However, when I am trying to get the objct back from Mongo, this way:

```
List<Object> objects = Object.list()

    def objList = new ArrayList();

    def filtered = ['class', 'active', 'metaClass', 'version']
    for(obj in objects) {
        objList.add(obj.properties)
    }
```

I am getting something like this:

```
"objects" : [
{
  "dbo" : {
    "_id" : "531afe54300426462e60c1ce",
    "key2" : "val2",
    "key3" : "hello",
    "version" : 1,
    "key1" : "val1"
  }
}, 
...
```

Of coarse I can take only the "dbo" of every object, and filter what I don't need manually, but it looks wrong. What would be the right way to get all the properties of an object including dynamic ones?

Definition of Object class:

```
package com.iibs.mongo

class Object {
    String id
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does:  `obj.getClass().declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }` help?  It would if you had an actual class, but it looks like you're stuffing values into an Object?

Comment: That's the thing, there are not declared :)

Comment: Have you declared a class called `Object`?

Comment: I do, but not the fields.

Comment: Calling it `Object` is going to cause you all sorts of pain... Can you post it's definition?